# What is the endpoint url for an outbound message?

Tags: workflowoutboundmessage

I've been following the instructions from here http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Creating_an_Outbound_Messaging_Notification_Service_with_Eclipse_3.2 and I'm confused as to where their endpoint URL comes from.  The example has it set at
IP:port/OM_Sample/services/Notification.

The IP and port are obvious, but where did they get OM_Sample/services/Notification from?  Having read through the sample I'm guessing its actually wrong and it should have been OMTest/services/Notification based  on the name of their project, but this still leaves me wondering where /services/Notification comes from?  Does an endpoint always take this format?  Is it based on files that are created automatically as part of the web service?

Answer (score 1):

The endpoint can be whatever you want it to be. Typically when I'm working with outbound messages, I just put something random in the endpoint at first to generate the wsdl. I then use the wsdl to build my service. Once the service is live, I go back into the outbound message and update the endpoint to point to wherever my service sits.

The endpoint doesn't need a specific format and will vary depending on the tool you use to build the service.

Comment: I'm writing mine in eclipse using the instruction in the link in my OP.  Its a bit out of date so I'm having to guess some parts.  Once I've generated my service I'm exporting it to a WAR file and hosting it on tomcat.  If I'm doing that, how do I know what the endpoint should be, or where do I specify it?  My service is actually working by setting it to project_name/services/Notification but I don't really understand why.

Comment: That's more of a java development question which I am definitely not qualified to answer! I don't know if that is java convention or if a result of the wsdl you imported.

Comment: I think its just something to do with the way the service is set up, but its not being explained in the instructions

Comment: Also, I'm only doing it this way because that's what these instructions suggest to do.  Is there a better way?

Comment: I've always used Jitterbit. Using it to create the service is really easy. No coding required at all. But it is kind of pricy.

Comment: Ah, the reason we're doing it this way is because its free!